# How to open history window of chrome browser from my application in android?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I m trying to open chrome history window from my application. Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        i.setPackage(PKG_CHROME);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("about://history"));
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        paramContext.startActivity(i);
```